# Returning json object nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, nightwatch.js

I want to execute json object like this from my html ul list like this

```
{name: "Nick", surname:"Kyrgios", age: "22", city: "Sydney"}, {....}, {....}
```

this is the html part

```
<html>
<ul>
  <li class="user">
    <div class="name">Nick</div>
    <div class="surname">Kyrgios</div>
    <div class="age">22</div>
    <div class="city">Sydney</div>
  </li>
  <li class="user odd">
    <div class="name">Nick</div>
    <div class="surname">Kyrgios</div>
    <div class="age">22</div>
    <div class="city">Sydney</div>
  </li>
</ul>
</html>
```

my nightwatch js file

```
browser.elements('css selector','ul li', function (result) {
  els = result.value;
  var i = 0;
  els.forEach(function(el, j, elz){
    browser.elementIdText(el.ELEMENT, function(text) {
      console.log(text)
    })
  })
})
```

This will execute

```
{ state: 'success',
  sessionId: 'cdfdda85-4348-4692-9ad0-2a5d10080a27',
  hCode: 151444186,
  value: 'Nick\nKyrgios\n22\nSydney',
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 0 }
{ state: 'success',
  sessionId: 'cdfdda85-4348-4692-9ad0-2a5d10080a27',
  hCode: 118749018,
  value: 'Nick\nKyrgios\n22\nSydney',
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 0 }
```

The main question is how can I change it to normal json format like

```
{name: "Nick", surname:"Kyrgios", age: "22", city: "Sydney"}, {....}, {....}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you run console.log - you are automatically getting a carriage return.  Each call to console.log moves you down one line.

You should be appending the results to a string

```
    var jsonString = "";
    els.forEach(function(el,j,elz) {
      browser.elementIdText(el.ELEMENT, function(text) {
        jsonString += text;
    })
console.log(jsonString);
```

Comment: Ah, Still nothing!